# Envío de correos con archivo adjunto con la librería nodemailer y express

Tags: angular, typescript, express, nodemailer

Estoy trabajando mi formulario de "trabaja con nosotros" en la que el usuario registra sus datos y un cv como archivo adjunto (.pdf, docx), código estoy obteniendo los datos de mi formulario en Angular y los envío a mi correo electrónico, el correo electrónico llega con todos los datos del formulario pero el archivo adjunto está vacío y con nombre attachments. Comparto con ustedes los fragmentos del código de mi app:

trabaja_nosotros.html:

```
<app-header-black></app-header-black>
<div class="container-fluid mt-md-5 mt-2 pb-5" data-aos="fade-up">
  <div class="row justify-content-around align-items-center p-3">
    <div class="col-md-6 ps-md-5">
      <h2 class="fw-bold mb-3">TRABAJA CON NOSOTROS</h2>
      <form [formGroup]="trabajoForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
            <div class="mb-3">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombre" formControlName="nombre" placeholder="*Nombre y Apellido" required>
              <div *ngIf="trabajoForm.get('nombre')?.invalid && (trabajoForm.get('nombre')?.dirty || trabajoForm.get('nombre')?.touched)">
                <small class="text-danger">Nombre y Apellido es obligatorio</small>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <input type="tel" class="form-control" id="telefono" formControlName="telefono" placeholder="*Teléfono" required>
              <div *ngIf="trabajoForm.get('telefono')?.invalid && (trabajoForm.get('telefono')?.dirty || trabajoForm.get('telefono')?.touched)">
                <small class="text-danger">Ingrese un número de teléfono</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-6 col-12">
            <div class="mb-3">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="ciudad" formControlName="ciudad" placeholder="*Ciudad" required>
              <div *ngIf="trabajoForm.get('ciudad')?.invalid && (trabajoForm.get('ciudad')?.dirty || trabajoForm.get('ciudad')?.touched)">
                <small class="text-danger">Ingrese una ciudad</small>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
              <select name="form-select" id="divisionSeleccionada" formControlName="divisionSeleccionada" (change)="seleccionarColor($event)" required>
                <option value="default" selected disabled>Seleccione una división:</option>
                <option value="Control de Plagas">División Control de Plagas</option>
                <option value="Limpieza">División Limpieza y Desinfección</option>
                <option value="Jardinería">División Prados y Jardines</option>
                <option value="Desinfección">División Desinfección y Sanitización</option>
              </select>
              <div *ngIf="trabajoForm.get('divisionSeleccionada')?.invalid && (trabajoForm.get('divisionSeleccionada')?.dirty || trabajoForm.get('divisionSeleccionada')?.touched)">
                <small class="text-danger">División es obligatoria</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="mb-3">
            <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" formControlName="email" placeholder="*Correo electrónico" required>
            <div *ngIf="trabajoForm.get('email')?.invalid && (trabajoForm.get('email')?.dirty || trabajoForm.get('email')?.touched)">
              <small class="text-danger">Correo Electrónico no válido</small>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <textarea rows="3" class="form-control" id="comentario" formControlName="comentario" placeholder="*¿Por qué desea trabajar con nosotros?" required></textarea>
            <div *ngIf="trabajoForm.get('comentario')?.invalid && (trabajoForm.get('comentario')?.dirty || trabajoForm.get('comentario')?.touched)">
              <small class="text-danger">Mensaje es obligatorio y debe contener al menos 10 caracteres</small>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="my-3">
            <div class="input-group align-items-center mb-2">
              <input type="file" id="cv" name="cv" (change)="updateFileName($event)" formControlName="cv" #cvInput style="display: none">
              <label for="cv" class="btn btn-secondary">Adjuntar CV</label>
              <span id="file-name" class="ms-2 align-items-center">{{ selectedFileName }}</span>
              <div *ngIf="trabajoForm.get('cv')?.invalid && (trabajoForm.get('cv')?.dirty || trabajoForm.get('cv')?.touched)">
                <small class="text-danger">Adjunta un archivo válido (PDF o Word)</small>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="text-center">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-dark w-100 py-3" [style.background]="divisionSeleccionada">Enviar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 mt-md-0 mt-3"><img src="assets/img/website/iconos/trabaja-con-ecovitali.svg" class="img-fluid" alt="Trabaja en Ecovitali"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<section class="mt-5">
  <app-footer></app-footer>
</section>
```

trabaja_nosotros.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { CorreoService } from 'src/app/services/mails/correo.service';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-trabaja-nosotros',
  templateUrl: './trabaja-nosotros.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./trabaja-nosotros.component.css']
})
export class TrabajaNosotrosComponent {
  selectedFileName: string = '';
  trabajoForm: FormGroup;
  divisionSeleccionada: string | null = null;
  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private correoService: CorreoService) {
    this.trabajoForm = this.fb.group({
      nombre: ['', Validators.required],
      telefono: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10)]],
      ciudad: ['', Validators.required],
      divisionSeleccionada: ['default', Validators.required],
      email: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
      comentario: ['', Validators.required],
      cv: [null, Validators.required],
    });
  }
  updateFileName(event: any): void {
    const input = event.target;
    if (input.files && input.files.length > 0) {
      this.selectedFileName = input.files[0].name;
    } else {
      this.selectedFileName = '';
    }
  }
  onSubmit() {
    if (this.trabajoForm.valid) {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('nombre', this.trabajoForm.value.nombre);
      formData.append('telefono', this.trabajoForm.value.telefono);
      formData.append('ciudad', this.trabajoForm.value.ciudad);
      formData.append('divisionSeleccionada', this.trabajoForm.value.divisionSeleccionada);
      formData.append('email', this.trabajoForm.value.email);
      formData.append('comentario', this.trabajoForm.value.comentario);
      formData.append('cv', this.trabajoForm.value.cv);

      this.correoService.enviarCorreoTrabajaConNosotros(formData).subscribe(
        (resp) => {
          console.log('Formulario válido. Enviar datos:', resp);
        },
        (error) => {
          console.error('Formulario inválido:', error);
        }
      );
      this.showSuccessAlert();
    }
  }
  seleccionarColor(event: Event): void {
    const division = (event.target as HTMLSelectElement).value;
    this.divisionSeleccionada = division === 'default' ? null : this.divisionColor(division || '');
  }
  divisionColor(division: string): string {
    switch (division) {
      case 'Control de Plagas':
        return '#71af32';
      case 'Limpieza':
        return '#542f88';
      case 'Jardinería':
        return '#ef7912';
      case 'Desinfección':
        return '#2791cc';
      default:
        return '#a7a7a7';
    }
  }
  private showSuccessAlert() {
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Datos ingresados con Éxito',
      text: 'Hemos recibido tu perfil y te contactaremos pronto para una entrevista.',
      icon: 'success',
      confirmButtonText: 'Aceptar',
    // }).then(() => {
    //   this.trabajoForm.reset();
    });
  }
}
```

Código backend de mi aplicación:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const express = require('express');
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const ejs = require('ejs');
const path = require('path');
const mysql = require('mysql2');
const multer = require('multer');

const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  database: process.env.DB,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
});

connection.connect((err) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log("Error al conectar a la base de datos ", err);
  } else {
    console.log("Conexión exitosa ");
  }
});

const emailUsuario = process.env.EMAIL_USER_1;
const contraseñaUsuario = process.env.EMAIL_PASS_1;
const destinatario = process.env.DESTINATARIO_EMAIL;
const cc = process.env.CORREOCC;

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  filename: function(res, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname) // Utiliza el nombre original del archivo
  },
  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, `./Cvs`) // Folder donde se almacenan los archivos
  },
});

const upload = multer({storage});

const enviarCorreoYGuardarDatos = async (req, res, template, correoCC) => {
  try {
    const { nombre, telefono, email, comentario, divisionEmpresarial, tema, tipo, divisionSeleccionada, ciudad, cv } = req.body;

    // Modificación de strings para cada endpoint
    const config = {
      '/enviar-correo/divisiones-empresariales': {
        from:`"Nuevo Cliente" <${email}>`,
        subject: "Nuevo Cliente desde la Web",
      },
      '/enviar-correo/at-cliente': {
        from: `"Nuevo Cliente" <${email}>`,
        subject: "Nuevo Cliente desde la Web",
      },
      '/enviar-correo/at-proveedor': {
        from: `"Nuevo Cliente" <${email}>`,
        subject: "Nuevo Cliente desde la Web",
      },
      '/enviar-correo/responsabilidad-social': {
        from: `"Nuevo Cliente" <${email}>`,
        subject: "Nuevo Cliente desde la Web",
      },
      '/enviar-correo/trabaja-nosotros': {
        from: `"Nuevo Empleado" <${email}>`,
        subject: "Nuevo Empleado desde la Web",
      },
    };

    // Valida y suprime el número de celular para redirección
    if (telefono.length === 10 && telefono.startsWith("09")) {
      const numeroWhatsApp = "+593" + telefono.substring(1);
      const enlaceWhatsApp = `https://wa.me/${numeroWhatsApp}?text=${encodeURIComponent("Hola, veo que estás interesado en...")}`;

      const templatePath = path.join(__dirname, 'views', template);
      const htmlTemplate = await ejs.renderFile(templatePath, { nombre, telefono, email, comentario, divisionEmpresarial, enlaceWhatsApp, tema, tipo, divisionSeleccionada, ciudad });

      // Pasa valores de config para cada endpoint
      const mailOptions = {
        from: config[req.url].from,
        to: destinatario,
        cc: correoCC,
        subject: config[req.url].subject,
        html: htmlTemplate,
        attachments: [
          {
            filename: cv.originalname,
            content: cv.buffer,
          },
        ],
      };

      const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
        service: "gmail",
        auth: {
          user: emailUsuario,
          pass: contraseñaUsuario,
        },
      });

      const info = await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);

      let query = '';
      let values = [];

      if (req.url === '/enviar-correo/divisiones-empresariales') {
        query = 'INSERT INTO formulario_divisiones_empresariales (nombre, telefono, email, comentario, correo_destino, division_empresarial) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
        values = [nombre, telefono, email, comentario, destinatario, divisionEmpresarial];
      } else if (req.url === '/enviar-correo/at-cliente') {
        query = 'INSERT INTO formulario_atencion_clientes (nombre, tema_a_consultar, correo, telefono, comentario) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
        values = [nombre, tema, email, telefono, comentario];
      } else if (req.url === '/enviar-correo/at-proveedor') {
        query = 'INSERT INTO formulario_atencion_proveedores (nombre, tipo_categoria, correo, telefono, comentario) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
        values = [nombre, tipo, email, telefono, comentario];
      } else if (req.url === '/enviar-correo/responsabilidad-social') {
        query = 'INSERT INTO formulario_responsabilidad_social (nombre, telefono, correo, comentario) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)';
        values = [nombre, telefono, email, comentario];
      } else if (req.url === '/enviar-correo/trabaja-nosotros') {
        query = 'INSERT INTO formulario_trabaja_nosotros (nombre, ciudad, telefono, correo, comentario, divisionSeleccionada, cv) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)';
        values = [nombre, ciudad, telefono, email, comentario, divisionSeleccionada, cv.originalname];
      }

      connection.query(query, values, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Error al insertar datos en MySQL:', err);
          res.status(500).json({ mensaje: 'Error al almacenar los datos en la base de datos' });
        } else {
          console.log('Datos almacenados en MySQL con éxito:', results);
          res.status(200).json({ mensaje: 'Correo enviado y datos almacenados con éxito' });
        }
      });

    } else {
      console.log("Número de teléfono no válido");
      res.status(400).json({ mensaje: 'Número de teléfono no válido' });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error al enviar el correo:", error);
    res.status(500).json({ mensaje: "Error al enviar el correo" });
  }
};


app.post('/enviar-correo/divisiones-empresariales', async (req, res) => {
  await enviarCorreoYGuardarDatos(req, res, 'correo-divisiones.ejs');
});

app.post('/enviar-correo/at-cliente', async (req, res) => {
  await enviarCorreoYGuardarDatos(req, res, 'at-cliente.ejs');
});

app.post('/enviar-correo/at-proveedor', async (req, res) => {
  await enviarCorreoYGuardarDatos(req, res, 'at-proveedores.ejs');
});

app.post('/enviar-correo/responsabilidad-social', async (req, res) => {
  await enviarCorreoYGuardarDatos(req, res, 'responsabilidad-social.ejs');
});

app.post('/enviar-correo/trabaja-nosotros', upload.single('cv'), async (req, res) => {
  const correoCC = cc;
  await enviarCorreoYGuardarDatos(req, res, 'trabaja-nosotros.ejs', correoCC);
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Backend iniciado en http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

He probado con varias soluciones que he encontrado en internet pero no logro resolver el problema. Lo más reciente que he intentado es colocar directamente el contenido del archivo adjunto (cv.buffer) al definir el attachment en mailOptions